# Error while running SharePoint Configuration Wizard before upgrade

Tags: configuration-wizard, patching, upgrade-sharepoint

I am trying to to run SharePoint Configuration Wizard before starting the new patch. Even though, I have not made any upgrades yet, I am facing the below error:

> An exception of type System.IO.IOException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\3ff6d5fa-1354-4794-b1ef-8b72096f83eb\' is denied.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to run it with the same account with which you installed the SharePoint.

Comment: Anand is right, restart SharePoint and SQL Servers ans you will be fine. I was!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following problem, I checked for the permissions the account has with which I am trying to run the configuration wizard. I also tried with the System Account/ Farm account but still the same error was displayed.

I came across two blogs which had the same steps as given [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamesway/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache/). In both of the blogs, it shows that the error is because of the config cache file. Instead of following those steps, I tried resetting the IIS and that didn't work. Then, I just restarted the servers, and the Configuration Wizard worked fine.